# Spring Cloud : FeignClient feign.FeignException$NotFound: status 404 reading RoomReservationService#getRoomReservationsForDate(String)

Tags: java, spring, cloud, feign

Hi i recently learn spring cloud with feign client and eureka but having trouble opening my web app what i got is the

> feign.FeignException$NotFound: status 404 reading 
>   RoomReservationService#getRoomReservationsForDate(String)
>
> `and The error at`
>   com.frankmoley.webapp.reservation.ReservationController.getReservations(ReservationController.java:42)

Here is My code for RoomReservationService

```
package com.frankmoley.webapp.reservation.client;

import com.frankmoley.webapp.reservation.domain.Room;
import com.frankmoley.webapp.reservation.domain.RoomReservation;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by frankmoley on 5/23/17.
 */

@FeignClient("RESERVATIONBUSINESSSERVICES")
public interface RoomReservationService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rooms", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Room> getAllRooms(@RequestParam(name="roomNumber", required=false)String roomNumber);

    @RequestMapping(value="/roomReservations/{date}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<RoomReservation> getRoomReservationsForDate(@PathVariable("date") String date);
}
```

And My ReservationController

```
package com.frankmoley.webapp.reservation;

import com.frankmoley.webapp.reservation.client.RoomReservationService;
import com.frankmoley.webapp.reservation.domain.Room;
import com.frankmoley.webapp.reservation.domain.RoomReservation;

import io.micrometer.core.instrument.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/reservations")
public class ReservationController {

    private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    private final RoomReservationService roomReservationService;


    @Autowired
    public ReservationController(RoomReservationService roomReservationService){
        super();
        this.roomReservationService = roomReservationService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getReservations(@RequestParam(value="date", required=false)String dateString, Model model){
        String date = dateString;
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(dateString)){
            date = this.createTodayDateString();
        }
        List<Room> rooms = this.roomReservationService.getAllRooms("P1");
        List<RoomReservation> roomReservations = this.roomReservationService.getRoomReservationsForDate(date);
        model.addAttribute("roomReservations", roomReservations);
        return "reservations";
    }

    public String createTodayDateString(){
        return DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date());
    }
}
```

I've been searching anywhere but couldn't find the answer
Please Help Me

Comment: it looks like you'll need to configure the url on feign client

Comment: Please attach your configuration yml and controller with /rooms endpoints

Answer (score 0):

Since it's 404 it's not finding the url to configure the client. Looks like you need to configure the url for feign client. The configuration can be done through application yaml's

E.g. 
application.yaml

```
RESERVATIONBUSINESSSERVICES: 
                         url: http:localhost:8080/reservationbusinessservice/
```

RoomReservationService

```
  @FeignClient(name = "RESERVATIONBUSINESSSERVICES", url = "${RESERVATIONBUSINESSSERVICES.url}",
```

Comment: Why we should use port information here? Cant we make it configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use servlet context path, if you use it, you need to include context path in Feign Client method